# jqgrid : is it possible to insert a section-roll-up bar every 'n' records?

Tags: jqgrid, grouping, expand

With the jqGrid is it possible to insert a section bar every 'n' records where clicking on the section-bar would toggle section expand/collapse? I am looking for a way to control the displayed height of the grid when I have set its height=100%.   Here is pseudo-html showing such a section-bar inserted every 5 rows. The last section has only 2 rows. The section-bar would not have to have column-names.

```
 <table id='jq-table'>
   <div class='column-headers'>name....city....postal code<div>
  <div class='section-bar'>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
  </div>
  <div class='section-bar'>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>
  </div>
   <div class='section-bar'>
       <row>  some data </row>
       <row>  some data </row>

  </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [subgrid feature](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0giikm.htm).